# C++/STL Default comparator

Tags: c++, stl

I ma writing a template function that takes a vector of elements and does a sequence of some operations on it. One of these operation is std::sort().

Naturally, client code needs to supply a comparator functor. I do not want the client code to specify a value for this parameter if it passes in a container of well-known types (ints, strings, etc.). How should I define the default value of my Comp template parameter?

```
template<typename Container, typename Comp=????>
void my_func(Container elements, Comp comp) {
  ...
  std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), comp);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `std::sort` might not be efficient on `std::list`; for this reason `std::list` has a `.sort` member function.

Comment: typo in your code, you wrote "typenam Container", it should be "typename"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::sort uses "Less" as default comparator. So to keep it consistent:

```
template<typename Container, typename Comp = std::less<typename Container::value_type> >
void my_func(Container& elements, Comp comp = Comp())
{
  std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), comp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Container, typename Comp=std::less<typename Container::value_type>>
void my_func(Container elements, Comp comp = Comp()) {
  //...
  std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), comp);
  //...
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    my_func(v);
}
```

Note also `Comp comp = Comp()`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't default the template itself but rather the parameter of the function into something akin to `std::greater` or `std::less` for `>` and `<` respectively. `std::sort` uses `std::less` by default.

If you want to get the template parameter for it then there is a proposal to make `std::greater<>` to work for generalised types called [N3421](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm) that was actually accepted for C++14.

However until then you can do `std::greater<typename Container::value_type>`. You can opt to remove the reference or cv qualifiers using type_traits if you wish.

`<functional>` has other default comparisons but those two are the most common.

So a "complete" solution would be something like this:

```
template<typename Container, typename Comp>
void my_func(Container& elements, Comp comp = std::less<typename Container::value_type>()) {
  std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), comp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is 2 issues:

1. to make default behavior you must suplly `less<T>` as a functor.
2. Your function is taking a **copy** so, the copy will be sorted, unless you take a refence to `Container` instead.

Example how to make this:

```
#include <functional>
template<typename Container, typename Comp=std::less<typename Container::value_type> >
void my_func(Container &elements, Comp comp = Comp() )
{
  std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), comp);
}
// A partial specialisation for std::list
#include <list>
template<typename ContainerValueType, typename Allocator, typename Comp=std::less<ContainerValueType> >
void my_func(std::list<ContainerValueType, Allocator> &elements, Comp comp = Comp() )
{
  elements.sort(comp);
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the only one to correct the pass-by-value issue.